# facebook like button (plugin) gives error when liking facebook.com page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fbml, facebook-page

I'm trying to add the facebook like button plugin to a site, and the target URL is a facebook.com page.

When I click the button, it changes to show that I like the page, then immediately changes back with a red "Error" next to it. However, the button has actually worked - if I reload the page with the button, it lists me among the likers, and if I go to the facebook page, it registers that I've liked it.

Here's my test page: http://www.graham-price.co.uk/facebook/
NB. The like button is the xfbml version, not iframe.

Also just noticed that this works fine with box_count and button_count versions, just not the standard version.

YellowTail Australia is the button that doesn't work. YellowTail Canada (for some reason) works fine. I'm an admin on both of these pages and the settings appear identical to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... that's strange. It doesn't even work with the developer sandbox code.. (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) Try contacting facebook support for this problem.If you ever manage to do that please let me know how you did it ... I'm trying for about 3 months now :)

Comment: @The Devil - cheers, I'll submit a bug :(

Comment: @The Devil - thanks for pointing out that it doesn't work in the sandbox, that was the clincher that it was nothing to do with my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitted a [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15730) to Facebook and it turns out that the reason this doesn't work is that the Facebook page the like button points to has an age restriction on it. Since you can't view that page in Facebook unless you're over 18, you shouldn't be able to like it from outside Facebook.

Still, the error is unexpected behaviour and only appears for standard like buttons (not box count or button count), and Facebook has marked it a duplicate of an [existing bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15578).